# Automatically Deduct quantity sold from quantity in the stock and display in datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Have been trying this but i havent find the solution. I am trying to implement A POS. So I have 2 database tables one is tblproducts that store the products in the supermarket and has the following fields: productId,ProductName,ProductCategory,Quantity,MinimumQuantity,UnitPrice,Manufacturer. and the second table is tblsales that stores the products tht has been sold and has the followinf fields: ProductId,ProductName,Qty,Unitprice,amount, QuantityRemaining. The information on the tblsales is displayed in the datagridview.

Now i am having a problem whereby I want the system to automatically deduct Qty the customer buys in tblsales from the total Quantity in tblproducts  and display in the datagrid. and also check that the minimum quantity is not reached..
any Mysql queries someone to help.

Comment: You need to share the code which you wrote for this and tell us which part of it is not working as expected.

Comment: What have you tried?  What isn't working?  It sounds like you're asking how to subtract one number from another and save it in a database.  That seems like something you should be able to attempt.  Note also that your table structure appears to be storing the same data in multiple places, which is likely leading to your confusion.  When you have multiple sources of truth, you have no source of truth.

Comment: In the button that adds the sold items to the datagrid, I have written a query : "INSERT INTO tblsales(Pid,Description,Qty,UnitPrice,Amount,QuantityInHand) VALUES('"+txtpId.text+"','"+txtname.text+"','"+txtQty.text+"','"+txtUnitPrice.text+"','"+txtAmount.text+"',("UPDATE tblsales Set QuantityInHand=Quantity-Qty WHERE productId=@productId )"

but it displays 0 in the quantityInStock in the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont need a specific warehouse quantity I would let the tblProducts maintain the actual quantity available for sale.

the Qty in the tblSales is the sold quantity for the actual sale.

by the way are there no sales id to group the lines in the tblSales?

How to handle the issue:

When you want to insert a new sale for a product, you create a transaction and deduct the sold quantity from the tblProduct and insert the new sale into the tblSales inside the same transaction.

This way the tblProducts will always reflect the current quantity in stuck.

You can use an implicit transaction scope like this to wrap your SqlConnection

```
string connectionString = "";
int productId = 0;
int soldQuantity = 1;
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var insertSaleCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblsales(Pid,Description,Qty,UnitPrice‌​) VALUES(@ProductId, @Description, @SoldQuantity, @UnitPrice)", sqlCon);
        insertSaleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", productId);
        insertSaleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoldQuantity", soldQuantity);
        insertSaleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "ENTER PRODUCT DESCRIPTION");
        insertSaleCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", 1234.00);
        insertSaleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var updateProductCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblproducts Set Quantity=Quantity-@SoldQuantity WHERE productId=@ProductId", sqlCon);
        updateProductCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", productId);
        updateProductCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoldQuantity", soldQuantity);
        updateProductCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

this is only a simple solution but, there are a lot of ways to implement this.

Comment: how do i go about creating that trabsaction now.. that is where i am now

Comment: the easiest way is to use TransactionScope

here is a link with a sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope

Comment: I updated the answer with a little shorter sample of using TransactionScope

Comment: can you mind chatting with me . because i cant get to understand.

Comment: I can't chat but I tried to add the code above hope it helps, if you need to see the actual quantity on hand in the girdview you need to join the tables by productId and use from the tblproducts.quantity asn the quantityOnHand

Comment: Thank Thomas for the idea